Integrating Google Assistant App Actions with Android widgets via custom intents
I successfully implemented a custom intent by following the Developer docs
https://developer.android.com/develop/devices/assistant/custom-intents 
The voice command works as expected, launching my app and getting the correct parameter values (item, country) in MainActivity, below is the Shortcuts file
<capability
    android:name="custom.actions.intent.GET_HISTORY_ITEM"
    app:queryPatterns="@array/queries_cap">
    <intent
        android:action="android.intent.action.VIEW"
        android:targetClass="com.test.assistant.new.MainActivity"
        android:targetPackage="com.test.assistant.new">
        <url-template android:value="mytestapp://historyitem.com/app-custom-requests/{?item,country}" />
        <parameter
            android:name="item"
            android:key="item"
            android:mimeType="https://schema.org/Text" />

        <parameter
            android:name="country"
            android:key="country"
            android:mimeType="https://schema.org/Text" />
    </intent>
</capability>

 <!--   string.xml file-->
<string-array name="queries_cap">
    <item>check the price of $item in $country</item>
    <item>get price history of $item in $country</item>
</string-array>

Queries:

Ok Google, open appName and check the price of Rice in India.
Ok Google, open appName and get price history of oil in Canada.

Now, I want to integrate this custom intent with Android widgets to display data on the Google Assistant UI. Specifically, I'm looking to use widgets to show information within the Google Assistant interface when the custom intent is triggered.
I've reviewed the documentation at  https://developer.android.com/develop/devices/assistant/widgets  but it doesn't provide much information about integrating custom intents with widgets.

Is it possible to implement this integration of custom intents with Android widgets ? If so, does anyone have insights or suggestions on how to approach this implementation?

Based on my research, I found that integrating Google Assistant App Actions with widgets using custom intents is not possible.
There is currently no available solution for this.
I contacted the Google App Actions team via email, and they responded that widgets are supported only for certain built-in intents (BII), such as:

Get Message
Get Exercise Observation
Get Food Observation
Get Health Stats
Get Item List

